# Conditional Probabilities multi coloured balls from a bag

Tags: probability

I have two bags
Bag1 : Contains 4 red and 5 black balls
Bag2 : Contains 3 red and 7 black balls

One ball is drawn from bag1 and 2 balls are drawn form bag2. Find the probability of 2black balls and 1 red ball.

How do I go about solving this problem?.

This is what I have come up with so far:

$$P(B,RR) + P(R,BB) = \frac{5}{9} \cdot \frac{7}{10} \cdot \frac{3}{9} + \frac{4}{9} \cdot \frac{7}{10} \cdot \frac{6}{9}$$

Thanks.

Comment: Consider cases:  Is the red ball drawn from bag 1 or bag 2?  Calculate the probabilities in each case and add.

Comment: This is what i have come up with so far. P(B,RR) + P(R,BB) = 5/9 * 7/10*3/9 + 4/9 * 7/10*6/10

Comment: @KrishnaKalyan why $6/10$?, you have to remove $1$  ball, like you did on $P(B,RR)$.

Comment: @KrishnaKalyan Okay except that you want $P(B,RB)+P(B,BR)+P(R,BB) \\ = (\tfrac 5 9\cdot\tfrac 7{10}\cdot\tfrac 3 9)\times 2+\tfrac 4 9\cdot\tfrac 7{10}\cdot\tfrac 6 9$

Comment: Sorry that was 6/9

Comment: @KrishnaKalyan Also, your $P(B,RR)$ is really $P(B,BR)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is what I have come up with so far:
>
> $$P(B,RR) + P(R,BB) = \frac{5}{9} \cdot \frac{7}{10} \cdot \frac{3}{9} + \frac{4}{9} \cdot \frac{7}{10} \cdot \frac{6}{9}$$

That's not quite okay.   The probability of drawing the red from bag-2 is twice that.   It is the old "two ways to draw the same thing" problem: red then black, black then red.

$$P(B,RR) + P(R,BB) = \frac{5}{9} \cdot \frac{7}{10} \cdot \frac{3}{9} + \frac{5}{9} \cdot \frac{3}{10} \cdot \frac{7}{9} + \frac{4}{9} \cdot \frac{7}{10} \cdot \frac{6}{9}$$